# Preventing the selection of another pivot item on a pivot control in a UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I managed to accomplish it with setting the SelectedIndex property to the desired pivot item, but a new problem occurred. You can see the animation sliding to the selected pivoted and back to the one you have specified. 
Does anybody know how to disable pivot sliding animation when clicking on the pivot item in the UWP application? Or maybe how to prevent the selection of the pivot item in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

[*Pivot* has *IsLocked*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pivot) property which should prevent from changing current item.

Comment: This property does not solve the problem. It just simply disables all other pivot items and does not show their headers, forcing you to stay on one item and not being able to navigate.

Comment: @AntonZhmyrov I thought you were asking for 'Preventing the selection of another pivot item', which is in short - stop the navigation. If not, then clarify your question. Other cases probably can be solved by editing the styles/templates.